# Действия с элементами массивов

Tags: python, массивы

Есть массив с числами. Нужно от i-ого элемента отнять i-1 й и вывести все в отдельный список.

```
X = [0,  0.125,  0.25,  0.375]

H=[0]

for i in X:

hk = X[i] - X[i-1]

Как быть? 

H.append(hk)

print(H)
```

Comment: Что должно быть с первым элементом?

Comment: Пусть он будет 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in` в python работает не так, в `i` передаётся не индекс элемента, а сам элемент.

Для получения индекса можно воспольозваться функцией [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

`enumerate` создаёт генератор, который на каждой итерации возвращает тупл состоящи из номера текущей итерации и нового элемент из исписка. 
Проще говоря он нумерует все элементы исписка.

```
X = [0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375]
H = [0] # первый элемент 0

for i, x in enumerate(X[1:]): # проходим по всем элементам кроме первого
   #enumerate нумерует i от 0 до n где n - длина переданного массива
   H.append(x - X[i]) # append добавляет 1 элемент в конец списка.
```

Comment: Вывело результат: [0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125]

Comment: Возможно я неправильно понял задачу, а как должно было?

Comment: Разве не [0, 0.125 - 0, 0.25 - 0.125, 0.375-0.25 ]?

Comment: Все, правильно, это мой затуп. Благодарю!